# ASP.Net variable to JavaScript

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I've been trying to pass an ASP.NET variable to a javascript function without any luck so far.

What I have is:

A master page that is using several .js files under folder root/js

I'm trying to create a public variable that contains the username of a person and would like to send it to a function that is inside one of the js files mentioned above.

```
public string username;
...
username = User.Identity.Name.ToString();
```

my js is:

```
$(document).ready(function {

var username = "<%= username %>";

var element = document.getElementById("userid");

element.innerHTML = username; });
```

After executing this I get <%= username %> and not the actual value.

I tried a second approach:

```
ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.Page, this.GetType(), "customScript", "AssignValue('" + username + "');", true);
```

but I get `function (e,t){return new x.fn.init(e,t,r)}` as a result... I don't know what to do.

Any ideas will be highly appreciated!

Thank you!

Comment: In which file is the assignment happening? (var username = "<%= username %>";)

Comment: you have to put assignment in the aspx file corresponding to the cs file which contains the username variable.In the worst case you can assign it to a hidden variable with run at server enabled.

Comment: It's in the Default.aspx file. I declare and assign the variable in the corresponding cs file for the aspx page just mentioned.

Comment: Is the JavaScript function within the ASPX page or an external JavaScript file?

Comment: It's an external JavaScript file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// aspx
<asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="hfUserName" />

// page_load:
hfUserName.Value = username;

// js
$(function() {
   $("#userid").text($("input[id$='hfUserName']").val());
});
```

Comment: Is there a way to do it without a hidden field?